# NestJs Cookies when serving API into Heroku

Tags: heroku, cookies, nuxt.js, nestjs, netlify

```
const validateUser = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);
const jwt = await this.authService.login(validateUser);

const cookie = response.cookie('jwt', jwt.access_token, { httpOnly: true });
```

Environment :

- Nuxt.js host on Netlify
- Nest.js host on Heroku

I'm using cookies in local development to make request after being loged.

But when I'm trying to host the front and back into Netlify and Heroku, the cookies do not be set (with the same configuration)

Is there a config needed to make it work ?

**Edit :**

```
response.cookie('jwt', jwt.access_token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: true,
});
```

Google chrome need this configuration to make cookies working

Comment: You have this problem because of CORS, You didn't have problem in local mode because domains were same.

Comment: I don't think so. Because I'm using that : 

app.enableCors({
 origin: ['localhost:3000', 'test.netlify.app'], credentials: true, 
});